# Why does a single RC network does not provide 90 degree phase shift?

Tags: oscillator

[image: schematic and output waveforms]

In an RC phase shift oscillator, we are using three RC network to produce 180 degree phase shift. Can't we use two RC network to produce a 180 degree phase shift?

Answer (score 5):

A single RC network will provide 90 degrees in the extreme but the problem is that the amplitude of the output will be zero.

Consider a 10kHz voltage feeding a grounded 10uF capacitor - the current in the capacitor leads the voltage by 90º as you'd expect - this is always the case with capacitors. I always remember it by CIVIL - in a (C)apacitor I (current) comes before V(oltage) and V(oltage) comes before I in an inductor(L).

So if you have a 0.1 ohm series resistor feeding the capacitor the current will be less than 90º leading - probably between 85º and 90º at 10kHz (EDITED from 89º). As the resistor value increases so the angle of the current reduces back towards 0º.

If the resistor were 10kohm, it would be defining the phase angle more than the capacitor and the phase angle would be closer to 0º.

So it's theoretically impossible to provide 180º phase shift with two RC networks. Making one RC network provide 60º is very easy and cascading three does the job.

Does this make sense?

Comment: your answer obeys phi=arc tan(Xc/R). but as resistor value varies only drop across varies. no changes in phase. See the image attached.

Comment: As you can see in the image, when R is changed, current in the circuit is modified but not its phase with V. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: @bharaththink there are phase changes but they are small changes with R at 0.1 ohms. This is a fundamental principle of RC networks. At 10kHz, a 10uF has an impedance of 1.59 ohms. If you used a 1.59 ohm resistor in series what would you expect the phase angle to be?

Comment: With 0.1ohm and 10uF the phase angle is 86.4º and when both are the same impedance the angle is 45º.

Comment: can u give me qualitative analysis how resistance value changes the phase of current in circuit, without that equation that i mentioned earlier

Comment: You should begin with Q = CV and differentiate to get \$\frac{dQ}{dt} = C\frac{dV}{dt}\$. this of course equals current through the capacitor but it is also the current through the resistor. Can you take it from here yourself. If not maybe raise this as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

> Can't we use two RC network to produce180 degree phase shift?

You haven't asked the entire question.  The entire question is:

*Can't we use two RC network to produce180 degree phase shift **at some desired frequency**?*

Don't forget, you want to be able to *choose* the frequency at which the phase shift is 180º and 2 RC networks will not give you this degree of freedom.

In fact, it's straightforward to show that

(1) for a high-pass 2nd order RC network, the phase shift only *approaches* 180º as the frequency goes to zero where the amplitude response goes to zero.

(2) for a low-pass 2nd order RC network, the phase shift only *approaches* -180º as the frequency goes to infinity where the amplitude response goes to zero.

So, you need at least a 3rd order network such that, *at some desired frequency in-between zero and infinity*, the phase shift is 180º and the amplitude response is non-zero.

> My question is "is it not possible to get exactly 90 degree phase
>   shift with a simple RC network"

The answer is similar and related to the above:

(1) for a high-pass simple RC network, the phase shift only approaches 90º as the frequency goes to zero where the amplitude response goes to zero.

(2) for a low-pass simple RC network, the phase shift only approaches -90º as the frequency goes to infinity where the amplitude response goes to zero.

The mathematical justification follows:

For a high-pass RC network, the magnitude and phase response are:

$$|H| = \dfrac{\omega RC}{\sqrt{1 + (\omega RC)^2}}$$

$$\phi = \tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{\omega RC})$$

Now, recall that \$\phi = \$ 90º for \$ \tan^{-1}(\infty)\$ thus, the phase is 90º when the frequency \$\omega = 0\$.  *For any other frequency, the phase is between 0 and 90º.*

Also, not that when \$\omega = 0\$, the magnitude response \$ |H| = 0\$ so there is no output from the network when the phase shift is 90º.

For a low-pass RC network, the magnitude and phase response are:

$$|H| = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + (\omega RC)^2}}$$

$$\phi = \tan^{-1}(-\omega RC)$$

Now, the phase is -90º when the frequency \$\omega = \infty\$.  *For any finite frequency, the phase is between 0 and -90º.*

Also, note that when \$\omega = \infty\$, the magnitude response \$ |H| = 0\$ so there is no output from the network when the phase shift is -90º.

Comment: My question is "is it not possible to get exactly 90 degree phase shift with a simple RC network"

Comment: @bharaththink, see my update to my answer